# What is causing my javascript files to auto-format?

Tags: debugging, js2-mode

If I have a long line in a javascript file such as:

```
  let args = [options.loadRaw ? buffer : path.resolve(filePath)].concat(options.commands);
```

At some point when I keep adding to that line, it auto-formats into:

```
  let args = [options.loadRaw ? buffer :
              path.resolve(filePath)].concat(options.commands); // test
```

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this, because it's pretty jarring. I'd rather run this myself manually when I want to like with clang-format. I'm using js2-mode so I have a feeling it's that but I can't figure out what it may be or if it can be disabled.

I know it's pretty vague but I don't know what else to say. I'm mainly wondering if there's a way I can find out for myself. I did `C-h k` before pressing the space key but it's just `self-insert-command`, though I noticed that there's this in the help buffer for that function:

```
After insertion, the value of ‘auto-fill-function’ is called if the
‘auto-fill-chars’ table has a non-nil value for the inserted character.
```

But I checked and `auto-fill-function` is nil, otherwise that definitely seemed like the culprit. Then I saw this at the end of the help buffer:

```
At the end, it runs ‘post-self-insert-hook’.
```

Whose value is:

```
(sp--post-self-insert-hook-handler helm-find-files--reset-level-tree electric-pair-post-self-insert-function electric-indent-post-self-insert-function blink-paren-post-self-insert-function)
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I did `(setq post-self-insert-hook nil)` in the buffer and then pressed space and it still re-formatted the line, so maybe it's something else? I'm entirely at a loss.

I'm not sure if this is related, but to see if it was js2-mode buffers I also just noticed some other behavior when in the `*stratch*` buffer. If I type out a sexp with just `one` repeated over and over, once I get to the fill-column it starts adding spaces, like this:

```
(one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one      one one one one one)
                                                                                ^ fill column here (column 80)
```

That's certainly different from what happens in js2-mode buffers though, where the line is entirely re-formatted onto separate lines so that it fits within the fill-column.

I'm on emacs 25 in case that matters.

**EDIT**: Disabling auto-fill-mode fixes the issue. The problem is that I want to keep auto-fill-mode. It looks like `js2-line-break` is the culprit:

```
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-line-break-function) #'js2-line-break)
```

My configuration of auto-fill-mode is:

```
  (defun my-prog-auto-fill ()
    (setq-local comment-auto-fill-only-comments t)
    (auto-fill-mode 1))

  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-auto-fill)
```

What I don't understand is why, if I setup auto-fill to only apply to comments, and the variable that js2-line-break is being assigned to is called `comment-line-break-function` which gives the impression that it only applies when within a comment, why then is `js2-line-break` being called despite not being within a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was due to auto-fill-mode. I was under the mistaken impression that `comment-auto-fill-only-comments` would make auto-fill-mode only apply to comments, but actually it seems like it only applies to `comment-indent-new-line`.

The problem is that in js2-mode this is set:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-line-break-function) #'js2-line-break)
```

Then `default-indent-new-line` calls that:

```
(funcall comment-line-break-function soft)
```

and `default-indent-new-line` is called by `do-auto-fill`, the default function used for filling.

I ended up fixing my setup so that auto-fill-mode only applies to comments. I'm not sure if this approach is correct, but it seems to work:

```
  (defun my-fill-nobreak-predicate ()
    (not (nth 4 (syntax-ppss))))

  (defun my-prog-auto-fill ()
    (setq-local fill-nobreak-predicate #'my-fill-nobreak-predicate)
    (auto-fill-mode 1))

  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-auto-fill)
```

I wish there was a separate built-in mode like auto-fill-prog-mode, so that I could still opt-in and toggle regular auto-fill-mode whenever I felt like it. But this will do for now I suppose.